# How can I print specific rows in Pandas Data Frame? No solutions worked :(

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to print the rows of my pandas data frame which include key words (dog, cat or bird). I tried all the solutions mentioned on Stack Overflow, but my code only printed 2 rows and I could not figure out the reason. Here are the codes I tried:

```
dodo_data[dodo_data['title'].str.contains("dog")]

dodo_data[dodo_data['title'].str.contains(r'dog')]

dodo_data[dodo_data['title'].str.contains('cat', regex=False)]

dodo_data[dodo_data['title'].str.contains("dog|cat|bird")]

dodo_data[dodo_data['title'].str.contains(r'dog|cat|bird')]
```

I also tried to use a loop for this:

```
for line in dodo_data:
    if re.findall(r"dog", line):
        print("Dog found")
    else:
        print("Dog not found")
```

What might be the reason? Your help is much appreciated.

My data is named dodo_data include YouTube data about a channel called Dodo. It is a csv file with the following titles: 'title', 'id', 'publish_date', 'view_count', 'comment_count', 'like_count', 'dislike_count',   'tags' and I opened it in pandas data frame by using the following code.:

```
dodo_yt_videos_file = '/opt/apps/jupyterhub/exchange/dodo_soulmates_videos.csv'

dodo_data = pd.read_csv(dodo_yt_videos_file)
```

In the 'title' column, there is a description about each video such as "This Dog’s Dad Got His Last Wish". I should iterate through each row under 'title' to see whether each video is about dog, bird, cat or other animals. Basically, I need to make keyword search or use regex. I used all the codes above. I could only print 2 lines of codes.

Here is a part of my csv file:

```
title,id,publish_date,view_count,comment_count,like_count,dislike_count,tags

Great Dane Loves His 92-Year-Old Nana | The Dodo Soulmates,mOwoHv7MxFw,2019-10-28 15:12:58,299094,752,15167,58,animal video animals the dodo Animal Rescue dodo cute animals pets wildlife pet videos wildlife videos animals the dodo the dodo animals rescuing animals The Dodo Soulmates Soulmates Soulmates dodo soulmates the dodo the dodo dogs big dogs living with big dogs big dogs dodo great dnae the dodo great dane great dane dodo kernel the dog kernel the great dane service dog

Guy Risks His Marriage For A Stray 3-Legged Cat | The Dodo Soulmates,gTB6H931ZG0,2019-10-09 19:53:29,181320,1283,13254,262,animal video animals the dodo Animal Rescue dodo cute animals pets wildlife pet videos wildlife videos animals the dodo the dodo animals rescuing animals The Dodo Soulmates Soulmates soulmates dodo soulmates cat the dodo cats cat the dodo soulmates cat 3 legged cat cat 3 legs cat with 3 legs three legged cat zorro the cat stray stray cat
```

Comment: Can you include more of your code, and data? See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we are still missing some information, I thought it best to post this solution now and update it if necessary.

#### Data

```
title,id,publish_date,view_count,comment_count,like_count,dislike_count,tags
Great Dane Loves His 92-Year-Old Nana | The Dodo Soulmates,mOwoHv7MxFw,2019-10-28 15:12:58,299094,752,15167,58,animal video animals the dodo Animal Rescue dodo cute animals pets wildlife pet videos wildlife videos animals the dodo the dodo animals rescuing animals The Dodo Soulmates Soulmates Soulmates dodo soulmates the dodo the dodo dogs big dogs living with big dogs big dogs dodo great dnae the dodo great dane great dane dodo kernel the dog kernel the great dane service dog
Guy Risks His Marriage For A Stray 3-Legged Cat | The Dodo Soulmates,gTB6H931ZG0,2019-10-09 19:53:29,181320,1283,13254,262,animal video animals the dodo Animal Rescue dodo cute animals pets wildlife pet videos wildlife videos animals the dodo the dodo animals rescuing animals The Dodo Soulmates Soulmates soulmates dodo soulmates cat the dodo cats cat the dodo soulmates cat 3 legged cat cat 3 legs cat with 3 legs three legged cat zorro the cat stray stray cat
```

This is saved as `video_info_data.csv`.

#### Code

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

col_titles = [
    "title",
    "id",
    "publish_date",
    "view_count",
    "comment_count",
    "like_count",
    "dislike_count",
    "tags",
]

df_1 = pd.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer="../resources/video_info_data.csv",
    names=col_titles,
    skiprows=[0],
    dtype={
        "title": str,
        "id": str,
        "video_count": np.int64,
        "comment_count": np.int64,
        "like_count": np.int64,
        "dislike_count": np.int64,
        "tags": str,
    },
    parse_dates=["publish_date"],
)

title_re = re.compile(r"\b(?:dog|cat|bird)\b", re.IGNORECASE)

df_1["keywords"] = df_1["title"].str.findall(title_re)
```

#### Ouput

DataFrame output:

```
                 title           id        publish_date  view_count  comment_count  like_count  dislike_count                 tags keywords
0  Great Dane Loves...  mOwoHv7MxFw 2019-10-28 15:12:58      299094            752       15167             58  animal video ani...       []
1  Guy Risks His Ma...  gTB6H931ZG0 2019-10-09 19:53:29      181320           1283       13254            262  animal video ani...    [Cat]
```

Let me know if anything isn't clear and/or you have a question :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203000/discussion-on-answer-by-alexander-cecile-how-can-i-print-specific-rows-in-pandas).

Comment: @SamuelLiew Thank you! I really wish we had the option of doing that ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

try use `isin`. There is no sample data provided, so here is the general solution

```
lst = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird']
df = df[df['columnName'].isin(lst)]
```

you may want to check more information  here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Comment: This won't work if the strings in the column contain more than just the words 'dog', 'cat', or 'bird', eh.

Comment: @user3280146 Thank you very much. I tried this code now. When I run it, it does not give any results. Python just jumps into other code lines. Should I write something else to see the results? Sorry, I am almost new at Python :( My code looks like this:

```
lst = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird']
dodo_data = dodo_data[dodo_data['title'].isin(lst)]
```

Comment: @Reyhan see the comment I just made above.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes, it contains sentences. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @Reyhan Yes, sharing more of your code so we can get a better idea of what's going on ;p For one, I'm not entirely certain what you mean by _print_ in relation to the code you have shared so far.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I added more details in my questions. Looking forward to your response.

Comment: @Debdut Goswami  I received this key error: "None of [Index(['cat', 'dog'], dtype='object', name='title')] are in the [index]"

Comment: @Reyhan Can you include at least part of the CSV file? The goal is for people here to be able to **run** your program. Please see: [mcve]. I just realized that your post feels so familiar because you asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59013114/11301900) recently.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is just set `title` as the index and then use `df.loc[the required keyword` to get the row containing the value.

```py
df.set_index("title", inplace=True)
print(df.loc[['cat','dog']])
```

This will print out all the rows containing `dog` or `cat` in the row named `title`

Comment: Isn't _containing dog or cat_ incorrect? I'm quite certain that this will only print the rows whose title is exactly 'cat' or 'dog'.